# Set Theory: A\(A\B) = B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Supposet A and B be sets and B ⊆ A. Show that

```
A\(A\B) = B
```

The relative complement of A\B is

```
{x | x ∈ A and x ∉ B}
```

So, this is steps that I have made so far

```
suppose x ∈ A\(A\B), then
x ∈ A and x ∉ (A\B), then
x ∈ A and (x ∉ A or x ∈ B), and using distributive law,
(x ∈ A and x ∉ A) or (x ∈ A and x ∈ B)
```

I understand that if B is subset of A, then relative complement of B in A is every elements of A that is not in B (A').
Then relative complement of A' in A would be deleting the all the elements of A' which conclude it to be only elements of B.

But, not sure how above steps can be connected to A(A\B) = B.
It seems like I am taking wrong steps.

Comment: You didn't use that $B \subseteq A$.  THe result simply is not true if $B\not \subseteq A$.  Try to apply $B\subseteq A$ and your final line is $[(x\in A$ and $x\not \in A)$ or $(x\in A$ and $X\in B)] $ and $($if $x\in B$ then $x\in A)$.  So now if you go on.....

Comment: Welcome. Did you make any drawings (Venn diagrams, etc.)?

Comment: ...actually I guess as you are proving subsets you can conclude $x \in A$ and $x \in B \implies x\in B$.  But that's only one direction and we are not doing $\iff$ steps.  If we go the other direction or we do only $\iff$ steps we will need to use $B\subset A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything so far is good:

You got $(x ∈ A$ and $x ∉ A)$ or $(x ∈ A$ and $x ∈ B)$ and as $(a\in A$ and $a\not \in A$) is a contradiction proves that

$x\in A$ and $x\in B$ so $x \in A\cap B$.

*NOW* you haven't used the condition that $B\subset A$ yet....

But if we use the we have $x \in A\cap B$ and for all $y \in B$ then $y \in A$ so $x\in A \cap B$ so $x \in B$.

..... which.... actually would always be true  If $x \in A \cap B$ then $x\in B$.

What's going on?  Well, remember we are doing subsets and we have proven that

$A\setminus (A\setminus B) \subset B$.  That *is* always true.

Now we must prove $x\in B\implies x\in A\setminus (A\setminus B)$

We get $x \in B$ so $x \not \in B^c$ so $x \not \in A\setminus B$.

And either $x\in A$ or $x\not \in A$ so either

$(x\in A$ and $x \not \in A\setminus B$) or $(x\not \in A)$

Now we need $B\subset A$.  That makes $x\not \in A$ impossible.

So $x\in A$ and $x\not \in A\setminus B$ so $x \in A\setminus (A\setminus B)$.

And we are done $A\setminus (A\setminus B) \subset B$ (!!ALWAYS!!!) and *IF* $B\subset A$ then $B\subset A\setminus (A\setminus B)$ and $A\setminus (A\setminus B)=B$ if $B\subset A$.

=====

More generally we could have proven that $A\setminus (A\setminus B) = A\cap B$. Always.

We *did* prove above that $A\setminus (A\setminus B) \subset A\cap B$.

And if we let $x\in A\cap B$ we get $x \in A$ and $x \not \in A\setminus B$ so $x\in A\setminus (A\setminus B)$.

.....

This reconfirms that if $B\subset A$ then $A\cap B = B$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!